# Problemas com Middlwares - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou usando uma middleware no Laravel 5.4 e gostaria que se o usuário logado tivesse permissão 2 fosse redirecionado para /admin/inscricoes. O escopo do método handle ficou assim, mas não funciona o redirecionamento. Alguma ideia?

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next){

        // SE O USUÁRIO NÃO ESTIVER LOGADO REDIRECIONA PARA O LOGIN
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        }else{
            // SE O USUÁRIO QUE LOGOU FOR CANDIDATO REDIRECIONA PARA MINHA CONTA
            if($request->user()->permissao !== 2){
                return redirect('/minhaconta');
            }elseif($request->user()->permissao === 2){
                return redirect('/admin/inscricoes');
            }else{
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde você registrou o middleware na aplicação? É em alguma rota ou em todas as requests?

Comment: O que acontece, aonde foi configurado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss registrei nas rotas que estiverem o prefixo 'admin'. Acha que devo registrar em todas?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar os operadores `!=` e `==`? Acho que o valor está chegando como string e, assim, é diferente de um inteiro.

Comment: você está fazendo para o usuario logado né? troca o $request pelo helper auth()->user()->permissao, coloque também uns dd() para gente saber o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acredito que o problema seja na sua classe, pois nela está faltando a instância do RedirectResponse, que contém as propriedades de headers necessários para redirecionamento, tente adicionar esta chamada.

Ficará assim:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse

Comment: Na documentação há vários exemplos utilizando o *helper* `redirect` sem utilizar a classe `RedirectResponse`, então acho que esse não é o problema.